# Does macos codesign only sign executable which extension is .app

Tags: macos, codesign, code-signing-certificate

OS:

```bash
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G31
```

i want to sign a binary file named pipip, but get an error, from the error hint, we know that filename `pipip` is unsupported format. Do i have to change pipip to pipip.app ?

```
$ codesign -vvv -s v-ca --force --all-architectures --timestamp /Users/vzhong/test-capitan/pipip-cli/build/osspi/pipip
/Users/vzhong/test-capitan/pipip-cli/build/pipip/pipip: invalid or unsupported format for signature
```

`v-ca` is name of identify.

```
$ security find-identity -v -p codesigning
  1) 490E98B941A8B??????BC0711A62 "v-ca"
     1 valid identities found
```

Comment: You can sign binaries; I think the problem is more likely in your signing identity. What is `v-ca`? `codesign` accepts a keychain identity preference, the SHA1 hash of the certificate of the desired identity, or `-` for adhoc signing.

Comment: `v-ca` is name of identify. see updated description.

Comment: `.app` is actually a folder - adding .app to a binary probably wont fix your issue

Comment: Hmm, then how to sign this binary `pipip`?

Comment: Ok, so what actually is `pipip`? `file /Users/vzhong/test-capitan/pipip-cli/build/pipip/pipip`

Comment: It's a binary executable

Comment: Ok, but is it a Mach-O executable? What's the output of `file`?